# The most lightweighted VNC server and window-manager for Fedora?

Tags: vnc, window-manager, vncserver

In my company I am using Fedora computer and I wanted to set up a VNC there, so I can access it from my home computer, which uses Ubuntu.

Unfortunately our internet connection is not so good, so I am looking for the most light-weighted VNC server and window manager. I really don't need too much fancy stuff -- I just need to use eclipse and terminal window on my work computer.

Can anyone recommend something? I don't have an experience of setting up VPN, so if there is a step-by-step tutorial, that will be great as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most lightweight VNC server might actually be the worst. You aren't transferring the server itself, but video data, and smarter servers might deal better with poor connections. I cannot recommend any specific programs, though.

There might be better choices than VNC, too: FreeNX is a very popular alternative; there's also [Xpra](http://xpra.org/) and `xrdp` (Remote Desktop).

Out of lightweight window managers, there's the classic `twm`, Openbox, various tiling WMs such as `wmii`/`dwm`...